# WSO2 - Import SSL certificate into keystore

Tags: wso2

Working with WSO2 API Manager v1.6.0.   I have a signed universal SSL certificate from GoDaddy I want to use.   I am able to import the certificate into a new keystore I created along with the intermediate certificate.  When attempting to access the API manager via https I am getting an error that the root certificate can not be verified.   I believe my issues may be that the certificate chain did not or is not importing correctly.

Comment: Did you modify the configuration files to use the new keystore? You would need changes in `repository/conf/carbon.xml`, `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`, and `repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`. You might also need to set `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>` values in carbon.xml to your domain.

Comment: Yes I have.  I double checked all the setting changes however still getting the error.  Are there any special steps needed to import SSL certficates into the keystore ?   I have confirmed my universal cert is loaded into my new keystore and the client-truststore jks files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Was able to import the signed SSL certificate as a trusted Key-Pair into a new keystore.